# How to fix "Type 'Neo4jConnector' doesn't have expected attribute 'run' " in python file

Tags: python, neo4j

This is the code below for connecting and running `neo4j` and python . I have seen a `neo4j` warning from the code . Is that a severe warning or is it mandatory to fix it? How to fix this issue? The warning is `" Type 'Neo4jConnector' doesn't have expected attribute 'run' "`

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase


class Neo4jConnector:
    def __init__(self, uri, user, password):
        self._driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=(user, password))

    def close(self):
        self._driver.close()

    @property
    def driver(self):
        return self._driver


def get_nodes_by_id_name(tx, id_name):
    query = (
        "MATCH (r:Rule) "
        "WHERE r.id_name = $id_name "
        "RETURN r"
    )
    result = []
    for record in tx.run(query, id_name=id_name):
        result.append(record["node"])
    return result


def create_inbound_rule(connector, profileid, sender, receiver, message, processingflag1, ruletype):
    id_name = receiver + '_inBOUND_' + sender
    name1_inbound = receiver + '_inBOUND_' + sender + '_SFTP_STEP1'
    return_name = name1_inbound + '& SFTP_STEP2 created successfully'

    query = (
        "CREATE (r:Rule {sender: $sender, receiver: $receiver, "
        "message: $message, profileid: $profileid, ruletype: $ruletype, "
        "processingflag1: $processingflag1,id_name:$id_name})"
    )

    with connector._driver.session() as session:
        session.write_transaction(lambda tx: tx.run(query, sender=sender, receiver=receiver,
                                                    message=message, profileid=profileid,
                                                    ruletype=ruletype, processingflag1=processingflag1,
                                                    id_name=id_name))
        return return_name


def create_outbound_rule(connector, profileid_outbound, sender_outbound, receiver_outbound,
                         message_outbound, processingflag1_outbound, filename_output):
    id_name = receiver_outbound + '_outbound_' + sender_outbound
    name1_outbound = receiver_outbound + '_Outbound_' \
                     + sender_outbound + '_SFTP_STEP1'
    return_name = name1_outbound + '& SFTP_STEP2 created successfully'
    query = (
        "CREATE (r:Rule {sender_outbound: $sender_outbound, receiver_outbound: $receiver_outbound, "
        "message_outbound: $message_outbound, profileid_outbound: $profileid_outbound, "
        "filename_output: $filename_output, "
        "processingflag1_outbound: $processingflag1_outbound,id_name:$id_name})"
    )

    with connector._driver.session() as session:
        session.write_transaction(
            lambda tx: tx.run(query, sender_outbound=sender_outbound, receiver_outbound=receiver_outbound,
                              message_outbound=message_outbound, profileid_outbound=profileid_outbound,
                              filename_output=filename_output, processingflag1_outbound=processingflag1_outbound,
                              id_name=id_name))
        return return_name


def create_both_rule(connector, inbound_profileid, outbound_profileid, sender, receiver, message, processingflag1,
                     filename, return_name, id_name):
    query = (
        "CREATE (r:Rule {sender: $sender, receiver: $receiver, "
        "message: $message, inbound_profileid: $inbound_profileid, outbound_profileid: $outbound_profileid, "
        "processingflag1: $processingflag1, filename: $filename,id_name:$id_name})"
    )

    with connector._driver.session() as session:
        session.write_transaction(lambda tx: tx.run(query, sender=sender, receiver=receiver,
                                                    message=message, inbound_profileid=inbound_profileid,
                                                    outbound_profileid=outbound_profileid,
                                                    processingflag1=processingflag1,
                                                    filename=filename, id_name=id_name))
        return return_name


def create_inbound_basictx_rule(connector, tradingpartner_basictx, profileid_basictx, processingflag1_basictx, id_name):
    name1_basictx = "1.0.0_ELUX_INBOUND_RECEIVE_FROM_" + tradingpartner_basictx + "_SFTP_TO_BASICTX"
    name2_basictx = "1.0.2_ELUX_GENERIC_IN_FLAT_FILE_" + processingflag1_basictx + "_BASICTX_TO_CC_FINISH"
    return_name = name1_basictx + name2_basictx + "created successfully"
    query = (
        "CREATE (r:Rule {TradingPartner: $tradingpartner_basictx, profileid: $profileid_basictx, "
        "processingflag1_basictx: $processingflag1_basictx,id_name:$id_name})"
    )

    with connector._driver.session() as session:
        session.write_transaction(lambda tx: tx.run(query, tradingpartner_basictx=tradingpartner_basictx,
                                                    profileid_basictx=profileid_basictx,
                                                    processingflag1_basictx=processingflag1_basictx, id_name=id_name))
    return return_name


def create_outbound_basictx_rule(connector, tradingpartner_basictx, profileid_basictx, processingflag1_basictx,
                                 id_name):
    name1_basictx = "1.0.0_ELUX_OUTBOUND_RECEIVE_FROM_" + tradingpartner_basictx + "_SFTP_TO_BASICTX"
    name2_basictx = "1.0.2_ELUX_GENERIC_IN_FLAT_FILE_" + processingflag1_basictx + "_BASICTX_TO_CC_FINISH"
    return_name = name1_basictx + name2_basictx + "created successfully"
    query = (
        "CREATE (r:Rule {TradingPartner: $tradingpartner_basictx, profileid: $profileid_basictx, "
        "processingflag1: $processingflag1_basictx,id_name:$id_name})"
    )
    with connector._driver.session() as session:
        session.write_transaction(lambda tx: tx.run(query, tradingpartner_basictx=tradingpartner_basictx,
                                                    profileid_basictx=profileid_basictx,
                                                    processingflag1_basictx=processingflag1_basictx, id_name=id_name))
        return return_name


def edit_inbound_rule(connector, new_profile_id, new_message, new_processingflag1):
    s_id = dict["s_id"]
    return_name = 'Rule Edit Successfully'
    query = (
        "MATCH (r:Rule) WHERE r.id_name = $s_id "
        "SET r.profileid = $new_profile_id, "
        "    r.message = $new_message, "
        "    r.processingflag1 = $new_processingflag1 "
    )
    connector.run(query, new_profile_id=new_profile_id,
                  new_message=new_message, new_processingflag1=new_processingflag1, s_id=s_id)

    return return_name


def edit_outbound_rule(connector, new_profile_id, new_message, new_processing_flag, new_filename):
    s_id = dict["s_id"]
    return_name = 'Rule Edit Successfully'
    query = (
        "MATCH (r:Rule) WHERE r.id_name = $id_name "
        "SET r.profileid_outbound = $new_profile_id, "
        "    r.message_outbound = $new_message, "
        "    r.processingflag1_outbound = $new_processing_flag, "
        "    r.filename_output = $new_filename"
    )
    connector.run(query, return_name=return_name, new_profile_id=new_profile_id,
                  new_message=new_message, new_processing_flag=new_processing_flag,
                  new_filename=new_filename, s_id_name=s_id)


def edit_both_rule(connector, new_inbound_profile_id, new_outbound_profile_id, new_message,
                   new_processing_flag,
                   new_filename):
    s_id = dict["s_id"]
    return_name = 'Rule Edit Successfully'
    query = (
        "MATCH (r:Rule) WHERE r.id_name = $s_id "
        "SET r.inbound_profileid_both = $new_inbound_profile_id, "
        "    r.outbound_profileid_both = $new_outbound_profile_id, "
        "    r.message_both = $new_message, "
        "    r.processingflag1_both= $new_processing_flag, "
        "    r.filename_both = $new_filename"
    )
    connector.run(query, new_inbound_profile_id=new_inbound_profile_id,
                  new_outbound_profile_id=new_outbound_profile_id, new_message=new_message,
                  new_processing_flag=new_processing_flag, new_filename=new_filename, s_id_=s_id)

    return return_name


def edit_inbound_basictx_rule(connector, new_tradingpartner, new_profile_id, new_processing_flag):
    s_id = dict["s_id"]
    return_name = 'Rule Edit Successfully'
    query = (
        "MATCH (r:Rule) WHERE r.id_name = $s_id "
        "SET r.tradingpartner = $new_tradingpartner, "
        "    r.profile_id = $new_profile_id, "
        "    r.processing_flag = $new_processing_flag"
    )
    connector.run(query, new_tradingpartner=new_tradingpartner,
                  new_profile_id=new_profile_id, new_processing_flag=new_processing_flag, s_id=s_id)

    return return_name


def edit_outbound_basictx_rule(connector, new_tradingpartner, new_profile_id, new_processing_flag):
    s_id = dict["s_id"]
    return_name = 'Rule Edit Successfully'
    query = (
        "MATCH (r:Rule) WHERE r.id_name = $s_id "
        "SET r.tradingpartner_basictx = $new_tradingpartner, "
        "    r.profileid_basictx = $new_profile_id, "
        "    r.processingflag1_basictx = $new_processing_flag"
    )

    connector.run(query, return_name=return_name, new_tradingpartner=new_tradingpartner,
                  new_profile_id=new_profile_id, new_processing_flag=new_processing_flag, s_id=s_id)

    return return_name


def main(dict):
    uri = "bolt://localhost:7687"
    user = "admin"
    password = "password"
    connector = Neo4jConnector(uri, user, password)
    ruletype = dict['ruletype']
    # Initialize a dictionary to store the result

    if ruletype == 'Inbound':
        profileid = dict['profile_id']
        sender = dict['sender']
        receiver = dict['receiver']
        message = dict['message']
        processingflag1 = dict['processingflag1']
        create_inbound_rule(connector, profileid, sender, receiver, message, processingflag1, )

    elif ruletype == 'Outbound':
        profileid_outbound = dict['profileid_outbound']
        sender_outbound = dict['sender_outbound']
        receiver_outbound = dict['receiver_outbound']
        message_outbound = dict['message_outbound']
        processingflag1_outbound = dict['processingflag1_outbound']
        filename_output = dict['filename_output']

        create_outbound_rule(connector, profileid_outbound, sender_outbound, receiver_outbound,
                             message_outbound, processingflag1_outbound, filename_output)
    elif ruletype == 'Both':
        inbound_profileid_both = dict['inbound_profileid_both']
        outbound_profileid_both = dict['outbound_profile_id_both']
        sender_both = dict['sender_both']
        receiver_both = dict['receiver_both']
        message_both = dict['message_both']
        processingflag1_both = dict['processingflag1_both']

        filename_both = dict['filename_both']
        id_name = receiver_both + '_Both_' + sender_both
        return_name = receiver_both + 'both' + sender_both + 'SFTP_STEP1,SFTP_STEP2 created successfully'
        create_both_rule(connector, inbound_profileid_both, outbound_profileid_both, sender_both,
                         receiver_both, message_both, processingflag1_both, filename_both, return_name)

    elif ruletype == 'Inbound BasicTx':
        tradingpartner_basictx = dict["tradingpartner_Basictx"]
        profileid_basictx = dict["profileid_Basictx"]
        processingflag1_basictx = dict["ProcessingFlag1_Basictx"]
        id_name = "ELUX_INBOUND_RECEIVE_FROM_" + tradingpartner_basictx
        create_inbound_basictx_rule(connector, tradingpartner_basictx, profileid_basictx,
                                    processingflag1_basictx, id_name)
    elif ruletype == 'Outbound BasicTx':
        tradingpartner_basictx = dict["tradingpartner_basictx"]
        profileid_basictx = dict["profile_id_basictx"]
        processingflag1_basictx = dict["processingflag1_basictx"]
        id_name = "ELUX_INBOUND_RECEIVE_FROM_" + tradingpartner_basictx
        create_outbound_basictx_rule(connector, tradingpartner_basictx, profileid_basictx,
                                     processingflag1_basictx, id_name)
    elif ruletype == 'Edit Inbound Rule':

        new_message = dict["new_message"]
        new_profile_id = dict["new_profile_id"]
        new_processing_flag = dict["new_processing_flag"]

        edit_inbound_rule(connector, new_profile_id, new_message, new_processing_flag)

    elif ruletype == 'Edit Outbound Rule':

        new_profile_id = dict["new_profile_id"]
        new_message = dict["new_message"]
        new_processing_flag = dict["new_processing_flag"]
        new_filename = dict["new_filename"]
        edit_outbound_rule(connector, new_profile_id, new_message, new_processing_flag, new_filename)

    elif ruletype == 'Edit Both Rule':

        new_inbound_profile_id = dict["new_inbound_profile_id"]
        new_outbound_profile_id = dict["new_outbound_profile_id"]
        new_filename = dict['new_filename']
        new_message = dict["Message_edit_Both"]
        new_processing_flag = dict["new_processing_flag"]
        edit_both_rule(connector, new_inbound_profile_id, new_outbound_profile_id, new_message,
                       new_processing_flag, new_filename)
    elif ruletype == 'Edit Inbound BasicTx':
        id_name = dict['id_name']
        new_tradingpartner = dict["new_tradingpartner"]
        new_profile_id = dict["new_profile_id"]
        new_processing_flag = dict["new_processing_flag"]
        edit_inbound_basictx_rule(connector, new_tradingpartner, new_profile_id, new_processing_flag)

    elif ruletype == 'Edit Outbound BasicTx':
        new_tradingpartner = dict["new_tradingpartner"]
        new_profile_id = dict["new_profile_id"]
        new_processing_flag = dict["new_processing_flag"]
        edit_outbound_basictx_rule(connector, new_tradingpartner, new_profile_id, new_processing_flag)

    elif ruletype == 'Rule Search':
        # Call the get_nodes_by_id_name function to retrieve nodes by id_name
        id_name = dict['id_name']
        return_name = 'Rule Search Successfully'

    else:
        print(f"Unsupported ruletype: {ruletype}")
    connector.close()
```

I tried to solve this error to fix these warnings and it did not fix the issue

Comment: welcome to SO! as a first step, please try to reduce your Question to both a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the complete error message!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your functions e.g. `edit_inbound_rule` call a method  `run` that the class `Neo4jConnector` does not have. One fix is to work with the GraphDatabase.driver, as is done in `create_inbound_rule`.

For example, rewrite `edit_inbound_rule` like so:

```py
def edit_inbound_rule(connector, new_profile_id, new_message, new_processingflag1):
    s_id = dict["s_id"]
    return_name = 'Rule Edit Successfully'
    query = (
        "MATCH (r:Rule) WHERE r.id_name = $s_id "
        "SET r.profileid = $new_profile_id, "
        "    r.message = $new_message, "
        "    r.processingflag1 = $new_processingflag1 "
    )

    with connector._driver.session() as session:
        session.write_transaction(lambda tx: tx.run(query, new_profile_id=new_profile_id,
                  new_message=new_message, new_processingflag1=new_processingflag1, s_id=s_id))

    return return_name
```

Comment: Can you tell me is there any area to troubleshoot this code to be free of error

Comment: For the error in your question, just replace `connection.run( ... )` with `with connector._driver.session() as session:        session.write_transaction(lambda tx: tx.run( ... ))`

Comment: Should i be concerned about 'Access to a protected member _driver of a class' warning  in the code

Comment: If you want to achieve some sort of encapsulation, then it can make sense to access the driver via the property e.g. `connector.driver`. But that's another topic ... Did my suggestion fix your problem? If so, please mark the answer as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the output from print(dir(connector)) , the message is correct - there is no attribute named 'run'

> ['**class**', '**delattr**', '**dict**', '**dir**', '**doc**',
> '**eq**', '**format**', '**ge**', '**getattribute**', '**getstate**',
> '**gt**', '**hash**', '**init**', '**init_subclass**', '**le**',
> '**lt**', '**module**', '**ne**', '**new**', '**reduce**',
> '**reduce_ex**', '**repr**', '**setattr**', '**sizeof**', '**str**',
> '**subclasshook**', '**weakref**', '_driver', 'close', 'driver']

I'd look at connector.driver.execute_query as that will likely achieve what you are looking to do.